# How can move a LUKS container from the middle of a partition to the beginning?

Tags: partition, data-recovery, luks, cryptsetup

For the tl;dr, skip to the bottom.

I have a dual-boot setup with Mac OS X at the beginning of my drive and three GNU/Linux partitions at the end of the drive. I don't have the relevant machine on hand to give an `fdisk` dump, but here's a rough overview of the original disk layout:

```
/dev/sda1: EFI System Partition
/dev/sda2: Macintosh HD (main OS X partition)
/dev/sda3: Recovery HD (part of OS X's recovery system)
/dev/sda4: /
/dev/sda5: /home inside a LUKS container
/dev/sda6: swapspace inside a LUKS container
```

I'm reinstalling GNU/Linux on this system and as a part of that, I want to make `/` encrypted. However, that requires a separate `/boot`. In order to create that partition, I resized Macintosh HD and moved Recovery HD back to the end of Macintosh HD. I also took the opportunity to make my `/` larger. So the end result is a disk that looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1: EFI System Partition
/dev/sda2: Macintosh HD (main OS X partition) (smaller than before)
/dev/sda3: Recovery HD (part of OS X's recovery system)
/dev/sda4: /boot
/dev/sda5: / (larger than before, and now inside a LUKS container)
/dev/sda6: /home inside a LUKS container
/dev/sda7: swapspace inside a LUKS container
```

**tl;dr**: Here's the problem: due to the order in which I configured things, I now have a `cryptsetup`-created LUKS container in the middle of `/dev/sda5`. Because it's in the middle, nothing can find it to unlock/mount/recover it. How can I move my cryptcontainer to the beginning of the partition? Probably this involves two distinct steps (actually *finding* the thing on disk, then using that information to move it), but I'm not sure. Googling's turned up nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LUKS has a distinct header, you could find possible offsets with `grep`:

```
# grep -a -b --only-matching 'LUKS' /dev/sda5
1832480940:LUKS
1959072314:LUKS
2019974297:LUKS
```

For each possible offset you find, you could create a loop device and see if it's a valid LUKS device or not:

```
# losetup --find --show --offset 1832480940 --read-only /dev/sda5
/dev/loop3
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop3 luksloop3
...mount -o ro, ls, backup, umount...
# cryptsetup luksClose luksloop3
# losetup -d /dev/loop3
```

Once you have found the correct offset, you can move it to the beginning of the partition using `dd`. This is **dangerous**, if you get the offset wrong or cancel the operation, the data is lost. So you should make a backup first in any case.

```
# dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M iflag=skip_bytes skip=1832480940
```

See if it worked:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 luks
```

Restore from backup otherwise.